# NHibernate ICompositeType Implementation for Uri

Tags: nhibernate, uri, compositeusertype

Is there any ICompositeType implementation for `System.Uri`?

I want to be able to use this query: `where a.Uri.schema == 'https'`.

Comment: Am I schizophrenic stacker to stacker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a ICompositeType wouldn't be enough to run arbitrary .NET methods in a server side query.

Comment: Ultimately, I implemented a composite URL class.